# Facebook messages using restFB returns only 25

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Facebook restFB is returning 25 messages inspite of using the limit parameter.

```
Connection<Message> cnv = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/inbox", Message.class, Parameter.with("limit", 1000));
for(Message msg:cnv.getData()){
        String tag = msg.getId();
        JsonObject abc2 = facebookClient.fetchObject(tag, JsonObject.class); //LINE 2
        List<Message> comments = jsonMapper.toJavaList(abc2.getString("comments"), Message.class);
         System.out.println(comments.size());
}
```

Even if I add the Parameters.with("limit",100) to LINE 2 then also it returns only 25 messages. What am I doing wrong. Kindly help.

Q2) I think /me/inbox and /me/outbox are returning exactly the same data from the Graph API is it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch more than 25 post messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936946/how-to-fetch-more-than-25-post-messages)